# jQuery Datepicker onSelect event get class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to get the class set in the `beforeShowDay` function of a jQuery datepicker when a user clicks on the date. Something like this:

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    minDate: today,
    dateFormat: dateformat,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {         
        // set all the dates to have reserved class for now 
        return [true, 'reserved', 'this date reserved'];
    },
    onSelect: function(date, el){
        if ($(el).hasClass('reserved')){
            // on click, check if reserved class exists. 
            console.log('it is reserved!');
        } else {
            console.log('it is not reserved');
        }
    }
});
```

Every click returns "not reserved". How can I check the class of the clicked element?

http://jsfiddle.net/sf90zw72/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a lot harder than that, the `el` argument you're getting is an object containg the datePicker instance, not the element clicked, from the documentation

> ...receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as
>   parameters.

Only the date selected and the parent Datepicker element is included in that object, so you have to use those properties to select the element and check for the class.

Note that in your example all dates will have the class `reserved` as there's no condition, but I'm assuming that's different in the actual code

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#calendar").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                return [true, 'reserved', 'this date reserved'];
            },
            onSelect: function (date, el) {
                var day  = el.selectedDay,
                    mon  = el.selectedMonth,
                    year = el.selectedYear;

                var el = $(el.dpDiv).find('[data-year="'+year+'"][data-month="'+mon+'"]').filter(function() {
                    return $(this).find('a').text().trim() == day;
                });

                if ( el.hasClass('reserved')){
                    console.log('it is reserved!');
                } else {
                    console.log('it is not reserved');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sf90zw72/3/)

Comment: Wow thats really not the easy way :D

Comment: Dude you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be as simple as this:

```
    $jx('.date-picker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, $el) {
            if ($jx(this).hasClass('start-date')) {
                console.log('...');
            }
        }           
    });
```